# Call glGenVertexArray( ) but always return only one resource with '0' ID on android machine

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am using VAO on android 2.4 OS and EGL get VAO extension successful, all VAO's function return correctly.

But when I call `glGenVertexArray( )` to generate VAO resources, I always got the resource with '0' ID ( it can render correct, but I expect to use multiple vertex type with different VAO resource ID, not just return 0 resource ID to me ).

On IOS or windows OS, the VAO resource ID is increased unsigned int type ( `glGenVertexArray()` will return 0, 1, 2, 3 ... etc ID.

How I can solve this problem ? Maybe I forget to call any enable GL state functions or something else ?

Answer (score 0):

```
for ( _dword i = 0; i < 3; i ++ )
{
  GLuint res[4] = {0};
  GL_CHECK_ERROR( glGenVertexArrays( 4, res ) );
  WLOG_TRACE_4( L"Create VAO(%d, %d, %d, %d)", res[0], res[1], res[2], res[3] );
}
```

All res array receive (0, 0, 0, 0) after call glGenVertexArrays( ).

Answer (score 0):

Have you ensured that your context is set correctly?

I had a very similar problem on iOS; if the context is not set (ie it's null), then when you call an OpenGL function, it basically says "if(context == null) return;".

So, the call "works", it doesn't crash... but it does nothing. I determined this by initialising the VAO variable to something non-zero, and observing that GL wasn't writing to it at all.

Setting the context correctly fixed it.